# Get swagger model schema json

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Is there any API exposed by Swagger which returns Json Model Schema of the payload?

Ex. /v1/item

It should return the 'item' model json schema

Answer (score 1):

You could if you separated your Swagger definitions into different files and used [references](http://swagger.io/specification/#referenceObject) to aggregate them from the master Swagger doc, then each of them would be available in a different URL.